# ModuleNotFoundError on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

Any idea where I should look for a solution? My django project worked fine on pythonanywhere. I then added a new app to the project, which worked fine locally. However, when I git pulled the project with the new app to PythonAnywhere, I got the following error:

```
2018-10-18 23:38:56,622: Error running WSGI application
2018-10-18 23:38:56,637: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'catalog.apps'
2018-10-18 23:38:56,637:   File "/var/www/aceh40_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
2018-10-18 23:38:56,637:     application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Here is the content of the WSGI file:

```
settings_path = '/home/aceh40/aceh40.pythonanywhere.com/aceh40'
sys.path.insert(0, settings_path)


dotenv_path = os.path.expanduser('~/aceh40.pythonanywhere.com')  # adjust as appropriate
load_dotenv(os.path.join(dotenv_path, '.env'))

# Set environment variable to tell django where your settings.py is
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'aceh40.settings'

# Set the 'application' variable to the Django wsgi app
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: After you created the new app , did u update the git repository or re-uploaded the entire project before git pulling it on pythonanywhere?

Comment: I did, but your comment helped me find my error. I have not committed some of the files. Thanks!

Comment: Great..if u found my comment helpful => upvote

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with uncommitted files. Committing all files fixed the issue.